# ElementTree: Finding child without elements

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML document which contains multiple tags with the same name, such as the following:

```
<record>
    <lang type="1">eng</lang>
    <lang>fra</lang>
</record>
```

Now, if I want to find Type 1 elements, I can use

```
root.findall("./lang[@type='1']")
```

But what if I want to find only the elements which do not have any attributes, like the second one? Obviously, I can find all elements and then do an *if* check or *try*, but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ElementTree doesn't implement the full [XPath language](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), so it's missing things like Booleans, Number and String comparison functions.  As you've already realized, what you're looking to perform here is a negative attribute search, which isn't possible with the limited XPath implementation for ET.

The programmers for ET are relying on the comparator functionality of Python to provide those capabilities via the pythonic *if, check,* or *try/except* methodologies you've already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through your entire tree, printing all of the tags and attributes.

```
for el in tree.iter():
     print el.tag, el.attrib
```

Iterate through your tree starting at the `record` tag, printing all tags and attributes.

```
for el in tree.iter(tag='record'):
     print el.tag, el.attrib
```

Iterate through the `lang` tag(s).

```
for el in tree.iter(tag='lang'):
     print el.tag, el.attrib
```

I would also take a look at [Processing XML in Python with ElementTree](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/15/processing-xml-in-python-with-elementtree/). That should help you in figuring out different ways to parse XML nodes.